# Why does the kitchen faucet lose pressure and sputter?

Tags: kitchens, water-pressure

Only the kitchen faucet, all other in trailer work fine, will start with full pressure, lose the pressure, and if I turn the water off then back on, it sputters so hard that it can be felt on the counter. This only happens with hot water, cold runs fine. There is no leak under the trailer, and the aerator is not removable. What could be the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. I'm guessing its that faucet's hot water washer.

Comment: It almost sounds like a bad case of water hammer caused by an obstruction in the hot water line. Try closing and opening the the shut off valve there could be some debris stuck in it that closing and opening may clear. If not there it could be something at the faucet valve. You may need to disassemble  the valve and clean it out.

Comment: Air is getting into your water line somewhere, check all of the fittings for leaks

Answer (score 1):

The washer in your kitchen faucet's hot water tap is loose or worn, and is flopping around when the tap is opened. Replace the washer and you should be fine.